# sqlalchemy date error. Argument 'arg' is expected STR but got INT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database schema (which i cannot change) with dates. they are defined as:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
...
| access_date         | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

now, my model as this as defined:

```
 from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class logme(Base):

  id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  ...
  access_date = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default=0)
```

When i load the model i get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'int'>'
```

if I comment out the access_date everything works fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using `server_default=` parameter and instead, you need to change it to use the `default=` parameter.  More info in the links to docs below.

Maybe this will help? (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html)

> Scalar Defaults
>
> The simplest kind of default is a scalar value used as the default
>   value of a column:
>
> Table("mytable", meta,
>       Column("somecolumn", Integer, **default**=12) ) Above, the value “12” will be bound as the column value during an INSERT if no other value
>   is supplied.

You are using `server_default` parameter

```
server_default=0
```

which is explained here

> Server Side Defaults¶
>
> A variant on the SQL expression default is the server_default, which
>   gets placed in the CREATE TABLE statement during a create() operation:
>
> t = Table('test', meta,
>       Column('abc', String(20), server_default='abc'),
>       Column('created_at', DateTime, server_default=text("sysdate")) ) A create call for the above table will produce:
>
> CREATE TABLE test (
>       abc varchar(20) default 'abc',
>       created_at datetime default sysdate ) The behavior of server_default is similar to that of a regular SQL default; if it’s
>   placed on a primary key column for a database which doesn’t have a way
>   to “postfetch” the ID, and the statement is not “inlined”, the SQL
>   expression is pre-executed; otherwise, SQLAlchemy lets the default
>   fire off on the database side normally.

Comment: Try using `default` instead of `server_default`

Comment: note that `default` has a different functionality (happens in python and not in db) thus I think @Mandars answer is better

Answer (score 9):

I think the error is self-explanatory

```
Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' ....
got '<class 'int'>'
```

Change the line as follows :

```
access_date = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default="0")
```

Please put quotes around zero. Since the column is defined as `Integer` the server side default will be numeric zero, and not string "0"

---

On unrelated note, I think you need either `nullable=False` or `server_default`, not both.

When you say `nullable=False` you expect a value to be provided explicitly in your INSERT statement, so `server_default` won't be needed.

OTOH, `server_default` indicates that it is OK to **not** provide value in your INSERT statement, but DB server will still populate it with your `server_default`

Comment: Both `nullable` and `server_default` might be needed when adding a column to an existing table with existing data. Still, consider removing the default value if that is not your expected db behaviour.